# compile Ogre without NVidia card

Tags: ros-fuerte, debian, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to compile and install ROS Fuerte in a Debian box.

I have problems compiling Ogre, as my PC has an Intel Integrated graphics card, and Ogre seems to depend on nVidia.

Is it mandatory to have a nVidia graphics card? And if not, how can I take out this dependency?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34721/compile-ogre-without-nvidia-card/) by [BeLioN](https://answers.ros.org/users/2449/belion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2012-05-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BeLioN](https://answers.ros.org/users/2449/belion/) on 2012-05-23**:
I deleted the nvidia dependencies from the manifest.xml file , and add an "exit 0" to the ensure-nvidia-cg-toolkit-is-installed.sh script to avoid nvidia toolkit detection (I know it is not the solution). And now I am getting the following compilation error: BUILD FAILED: Plugin_CgProgramManager.so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For just compiling Ogre, I don't think having an NVidia card is really mandatory. Can't you just install nvidia-cg-toolkit for building it?

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1